# Refresh a single Kendo grid row

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a way to refresh a single Kendo grid row without refreshing the whole datasource or using jQuery to set the value for each cell?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

How do you define the row that you want to update? I'm going to assume that is the row that you have selected, and the name of the column being updated is `symbol`.

```js
// Get a reference to the grid
var grid = $("#my_grid").data("kendoGrid");

// Access the row that is selected
var select = grid.select();
// and now the data
var data = grid.dataItem(select);
// update the column `symbol` and set its value to `HPQ`
data.set("symbol", "HPQ");
```

Remember that the content of the `DataSource` is an `observable` object, meaning that you can update it using `set` and the change should be reflected *magically* in the `grid`.

Comment: What should we do if their is a custom template on a cell, which is un-editable, and that template calls a function. Calling set on the data item does not seem to redraw the template.

Comment: @jonperl I suggest you to ask it as a different question in order to make sure that others than me see it and have the opportunity of answering it. Anyway I tried it with templates and it worked. So, please post some code showing what you tried and showing what fails.

Comment: NOTE: 'kendoDataGrid' is now called 'kendoGrid' (or perhaps it always was)

Comment: @OnaBai when you say 'the content of the DataSource is an observable object' this only applies if you want to update the entire data set right and not just a single row? AFAIK I need to call 'data.set' for each column when updating a specific/single row

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, you are right! But that's the same for any _Observable_ object. _Observable_ is not something built-in in JavaScript language, the only way to intercept changes in an object is using some method that checks when a value is assigned and who is willing to know about it (the UI)

Comment: @OnaBai thanks. also it turns out that if a column is set to be non-editable in the model (eg. `model.Fields[0].editable == false` then if you call `data.set('ProductName', 'Cat')` on that column it won't be updated in the grid. I assume this could be fixed by a custom template if really necessary

Comment: Might be arguable but what does not "editable" mean? In this context and keeping in mind the UI part of KendoUI I try to understand that is about UI and not a full programming interface. The support for "Observable" objects is due to the fact that you need to update the UI and then we (the programmers) want to use it extending its scope...

Comment: I've tried both @OnaBai and Adam Yaxley's solutions.  OnaBai's solution works to begin with but ends with all kinds of scrolling and current row and cell selection issues.  Adam's solutions works beautifully with no side-effects.

Comment: @OnaBai var select = grid.select(); will not work in a popup editor. how can i determine which row is being edited?

Answer (score 34):

`data.set` will actually refresh the entire grid and send a `databound` event in some cases. This is very slow and unnecessary. It will also collapse any expanded detail templates which is not ideal.

I would recommend you to use this function that I wrote to update a single row in a kendo grid.

```js
// Updates a single row in a kendo grid without firing a databound event.
// This is needed since otherwise the entire grid will be redrawn.
function kendoFastRedrawRow(grid, row) {
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

    var rowChildren = $(row).children('td[role="gridcell"]');

    for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {

        var column = grid.columns[i];
        var template = column.template;
        var cell = rowChildren.eq(i);

        if (template !== undefined) {
            var kendoTemplate = kendo.template(template);

            // Render using template
            cell.html(kendoTemplate(dataItem));
        } else {
            var fieldValue = dataItem[column.field];

            var format = column.format;
            var values = column.values;

            if (values !== undefined && values != null) {
                // use the text value mappings (for enums)
                for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
                    var value = values[j];
                    if (value.value == fieldValue) {
                        cell.html(value.text);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else if (format !== undefined) {
                // use the format
                cell.html(kendo.format(format, fieldValue));
            } else {
                // Just dump the plain old value
                cell.html(fieldValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```js
// Get a reference to the grid
var grid = $("#my_grid").data("kendoGrid");

// Access the row that is selected
var select = grid.select();
// and now the data
var data = grid.dataItem(select);

// Update any values that you want to
data.symbol = newValue;
data.symbol2 = newValue2;
...

// Redraw only the single row in question which needs updating
kendoFastRedrawRow(grid, select);

// Then if you want to call your own databound event to do any funky post processing:
myDataBoundEvent.apply(grid);
```

Comment: What if you aren't doing editing on the grid itself, but instead in a popup. How do you determine the row that is being edited?

Comment: I do get myDataBoundEvent is a function variable in the code snippet above. But what kind of code actually goes into that function? Is there a live example of that I can look at? I am currently having code above without the apply call in the end after invoking the kendoFastRedrawRow method invocation and I see a spinning wheel, seeming to suggest that the browser is still waiting for something. Any pointers?

Comment: @Scott did you find a solution on - How do you determine the row that is being edited in a popup ?

Comment: No idea. This was over a year ago. :)

Comment: @Adam Yaxley, This is working fine for me, but is there any way to refresh all the columns in the row using json instead of dong each column like data.symbol = newValue, because my grid contains up to 60 columns?

Comment: This approach worked well with a plain grid, but another grid I had included columns that used templates with angular 1 parts, it couldn't handle this.

Comment: This is a very interesting input and i tested it. It works well for a lot of things.
In my case, with groups and aggregated sum it does not work on dataBound.
Thanks for your input.
my test: https://dojo.telerik.com/ikiDIZIY

Comment: @agDev If you're editing from a pop-up and working on the dataItem, you can use the uid property to get the row object like this var uiRow = grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']")[0];

Answer (score 9):

I found a way to update the grid dataSource and show in the grid without refreshing all the grid.
For example you have a selected row and you want to change column "name" value.

```
//the grid
var grid = $('#myGrid').data('kendoGrid');    
// Access the row that is selected
var row = grid.select();
//gets the dataItem
var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
//sets the dataItem   
dataItem.name = 'Joe';
//generate a new row html
var rowHtml = grid.rowTemplate(dataItem);
//replace your old row html with the updated one
row.replaceWith(rowHtml);
```

Comment: I don't know if they added the feature since you wrote your answer, but if you replace dataItem.name with dataItem.set("Name", "Joe") then you don't need to re-render the grid.  It will update itself.

Comment: Your right it will update the grid like in the different Onas' answer but it will re-render the entire grid and if you have filter it will hide the line or move it to other location (in sort).

Comment: Perfect! I added the following line of code afterwards to re-select the previously selected row: `grid.select(grid.table.find("[data-uid=" + dataItem.uid + "]"));`

Answer (score 2):

```
updateRecord(record) {
    const grid = $(this.el.nativeElement).data('kendoGrid');
    const row = grid.select();
    const dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
    for (const property in record) {
      if (record.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        dataItem.set(property, record[property]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: add some description to this and it will be better received.  It looks like very good code.

Answer (score 0):

With the Q4 2023 release of Kendo UI, font icons are being phased out in favour of SVG icons. At this time (Q1 2024) the SVG icons need to be injected programmatically. If a row containing one or more cells with SVG icons and whose parent columns have templates is redrawn using the above defined kendoFastRedrawRow function by Adam Yaxley you can preserve the SVG icons by adding making the following changes.

OLD CODE:

```
if (template !== undefined) {
    var kendoTemplate = kendo.template(template);

    // Render using template
    cell.html(kendoTemplate(dataItem));
}
```

NEW CODE:

```
let templateIsDefined = (template !== undefined && template !== null && template.length !== undefined && template.length > 0);
if (templateIsDefined) {
    //check for class k-icon and k-svg-icon
    let kSvgIconChildElementsInOriginalCell = cell.find(".k-svg-icon");
    if (kSvgIconChildElementsInOriginalCell.length > 0) {
    let templateAsDomObj = $.parseHTML(template);

    //check for class k-icon and k-svg-icon
    let kIconElementsInTemplate = $(templateAsDomObj).find(".k-icon");

    if (kIconElementsInTemplate.length > 0 && kSvgIconChildElementsInOriginalCell.length > 0) {

        //direct 1:1 replacements of template k-icon with k-svg-icon info from the original cell
        let x = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < kIconElementsInTemplate.length; j++) {
            if (kSvgIconChildElementsInOriginalCell.length > j) {
                let oldHtml = kIconElementsInTemplate.eq(j).prop('outerHTML');
                let newHtml = $(kSvgIconChildElementsInOriginalCell).eq(j).prop('outerHTML');
                if (template.indexOf(newHtml) === -1) {
                    template = template.replace(oldHtml, newHtml);
                }
            }
            x=j+1;
        }
        //inject extra k-svg-icon info from original cell
        if (kSvgIconChildElementsInOriginalCell.length > x) {
            for (let j = x; j < kSvgIconChildElementsInOriginalCell.length; j++) {
                let newHtml = $(kSvgIconChildElementsInOriginalCell).eq(j).prop('outerHTML');
                if (template.indexOf(newHtml) === -1) {
                    template += newHtml;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//render the cell using the template
let kendoTemplate = kendo.template(template);
let kendoTemplateHtml = kendoTemplate(dataItem);
cell.html(kendoTemplateHtml);
```