# Kendo DataSource Single-Row Read

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource

I have a mobile app that receives a push notification, when it does, I know there is a row that that needs to be updated.  I have tried two methods for retrieving just that one:

```
var row = data_source.get(<id>);
row.dirty = true;
data_source.sync();
```

This tries to fire an UPDATE, which I could shoe-horn into doing what I want, but it's conceptually wrong.

The other option that I have tried:

```
data_source.read( { id : <id> } );
```

Which fires off a READ request, with the ID in `options.data`.  When I try to hook this up, kendo complains about not getting an array back, and when I make the response into an array, it doesn't seem to work either.

How am I supposed to do this?  GET it outside the context of the DataSource, and set the relevant parts, and then set the dirty bit to false?

Comment: Any luck resolving your issue ?

Comment: @Bobby_D_ As far as I can tell, you're correct.  Though it seems like a pretty big omission...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kendo doesn't do single row read out of the box. If its not feasible to do full read(), you have to do what you proposed. Try following :

1)  make your server side read method to accept requests with or without id, without to read all items, with to read your one row.

2)  use [parameter map](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) together with isPushNotificaton flag to control the read request params

```
parameterMap: function(data, type) {
  if (type == "read") {
    if (isPushNotificaton)
          return { id : yourId };
    else
          return { id : 0}; // get all 
    }
  }
```

3) use [requestEnd](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#events-requestEnd) to decide how to deal with read result

```
     requestEnd: function(e) {
            var type = e.type;
            if (e.type == 'read') {

               // examine the response(by count/add additional flags into response object)
               var isFullReadResponse = ...;

               if (!isFullReadResponse) {
                  // DIY
                  e.preventDefault();
                  UpdateSingleRow(response, datasource.data());
               } 
            } 
     }
```

4) Implement UpdateSingleRow method as you proposed - .."and set the relevant parts, and then set the dirty bit to false", ([Refresh a single Kendo grid row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613098/refresh-a-single-kendo-grid-row))